# Mixed mode debugging with Resharper on x64?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I have an .NET 4.0 application thats mostly in C#.  It's got a managed C++ DLL that makes use of an unmanaged library.  I'd like to debug the library from within ReSharper, but I'm on x64.  If I use nunit and attach the debugger to the running nunit process everything works fine

is there any way to do what I need?

Comment: ReSharper doesn't have anything to do with debugging, so that's irrelevant. What problems are you seeing when you try to debug normally? If it works when you attach, it should work when you hit Start. Are you getting some kind of error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: @Joe - Resharper includes a unit test runner which can run a single unit test under the debugger.  That's what's being talked about here

Answer (score 4):

Actually there IS an issue with resharper here. We can debug in nunit, mstest and if we spin up out application and attach with a debugger. But basically no matter what you do you will NEVER get a breakpoint to hit in Resharper. And there is no error it just bypasses everything in the unmanaged code. There is at this point in time no solution that I can find that allows mixed mode debugging with resharper. Our organization struggled with this for several weeks. We eventually abandoned resharper for debugging in favor of plain mstest.

see the following:
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/290349

Comment: I am still experiencing this problem, more than 4 years later. :-(

Comment: Can't get it to work either. Seems broken still in Resharper ultimate 2016.2